# How to set proper path to offline OSM directory in QML ( not using qrc )?

Tags: qt, qml, openstreetmap

I would like to have folder with tiles `realTiles` in folder with .exe.

Of course I can add folder to qrc and everything is ok:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12
...
Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[0]
        zoomLevel: 14
        plugin: Plugin {
            name: 'osm';
            PluginParameter {
                name: 'osm.mapping.offline.directory'
                value: ':/realTiles/'
            }
        }
    }
```

So I copy folder `realTiles` to folder with .exe and folder one above .exe. So for example I have folder `realTiles` in this 2 positions:

`C:/Users/tom/Desktop/app/build-OsmOffline-Desktop_Qt_5_15_1_MinGW_64_bit-Release/release/realTiles`
`C:/Users/tom/Desktop/app/build-OsmOffline-Desktop_Qt_5_15_1_MinGW_64_bit-Release/realTiles`

And I tried with Plugin Parameter' value:

```
value: 'file:///' + applicationDirPath + '/../realTiles/'
value: 'file:///realTiles/'
value: 'file:/realTiles/'
```

and many other. Of course I can did mistake. What is a real solution to this?

EDIT:

```
main.qml


import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12
Window {
    id: win
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    width: 512
    height: 512

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[0]
        plugin: Plugin {
            name: 'osm';
            PluginParameter {
                name: 'osm.mapping.offline.directory'
                //value: ':/realTiles/'
                value: 'file:///' + applicationDirPath + '/../realTiles/'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
main.cpp

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <QQmlContext>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("applicationDirPath", QGuiApplication::applicationDirPath());
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give the full path

```
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.cache.directory"
            value: "C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/OSMCache"
        }
```

I have tried to change the cache directory it worked. So provide the full path in the value field.